# Redirect all the requests coming from specific domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I want to redirect all the requests coming from specific domain to specific directory. To be more precise I have two different domains i.e `example.com`, `example.tk` and both the domains point to a same server. The sever has two different directories i.e `cars`, `bikes`. I have created `.htaccess` file on root but not able to do the configurations. I want that all request coming from `example.com` should be redirected to `cars` directory. And all requests coming from `example.tk` should be redirected to `bikes` directory.

How can I achieve that successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This .htaccess file will redirect http://example.com/file.html to http://example.com/cars/file.html and http://example.tk/file.html to http://example.tk/bikes/file.html:

```
Filename: .htaccess

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !cars
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/cars/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.tk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !bikes
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.tk/bikes/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i think it will help you

for more reference : [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cars` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^bikes`